# How to handle underscores in the column name of Apache Ignite Cache/Tables

Tags: java, ignite, gridgain

My Ignite Cache "Person" is having fields as `id,name,city_id`

So my POJO class is like

```
private String id;
private String name;
private String city_id;
```

But in the IgniteRepository, When I am trying to write Query method as `findByCityId()` or `findByCity_Id()` or `findByCity__id()`, nothing works for me.

Is there a way to handle this or Only option is to use SQL query in the Repository `@Query`?

In normal MySql and Spring data, we used to add Column Name to change the column name as per our choice, so similarly what can be done here ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [QuerySqlField](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/query/annotations/QuerySqlField.html) annotation to customize POCO mapping.

```
@QuerySqlField(name = "CityId")
private String city_id;
```

Comment: It created another issue. 
If I am writing the method as `findByNameAndCityId(String name,String city);`
I am getting Exception, which says `org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'name' found for type 'String'`
If I am trying to make the method as `findByCityId(String city);`
Still the same exception `org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'cityid' found for type 'String'`

Only method working is `findByName(String name);`

Am I missing something ?